# How to add 'Open With' to folders in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, sublime-text

Sublime text allows you to open folders as projects. I'd like to be able to do this from the Windows Explorer, but there is no `Open With` menu item for folders.

How can I add that option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally I'd recommend [Default Programs Editor](http://www.defaultprogramseditor.com) for this task, but it doesn't support editing context menus for folders.

However, you can do it with a quick registry key. Take this, edit it to your app path, save it as `whatever.reg`, and double click to merge into your registry.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\shell\sublime]
@="Open with Sublime Text..."

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\shell\sublime\command]
@="\"C:\\your\\path\\to\\sublime_text.exe\" \"%1\""
```